# Do I ever get the last key for the 4th house?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm pretty far along in the game, and I still haven't caught wind of a key for the last house in the village. Is there actually any way to get into the last house, or does is remain locked for the entire game?

Comment: oh, oops, I thought I had looked through all the questions it thought might be duplicates. Guess not. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about the first house in the village. If so, no you never get a key for that house.